# How do I find what is trying to use upstart on my system?

Tags: 16.04, upstart, systemd, anacron

I set up email on my server last night so I could get error notification emails and I got a puzzling email:

The whole message is:

```
Subject:Cron <root@*redacted*> start -q anacron || :
Body: start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

Is there a way I can search for what is trying to use upstart and convert it to systemd?

Comment: Try this `journalctl -xe | grep -i upstart | less`

Comment: `start -q anacron || :` seems to be something that appears in `/etc/cron.d/anacron` on my old 12.04 box - but is replaced by a call to `/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d` by 16.04. I wonder if your `/etc/cron.d/anacron` is a leftover from an earlier version that never got updated properly?

Comment: I think that fixed it!   I ran dpkg -s anacron and it wasn't installed, so I rm'd the file.  I think you're right, leftover from old system.

Answer (score 0):

1. check to see if anacron is installed with `dpkg -s anacron` (it probably isn't)
2. If it isn't, go ahead and `rm /etc/cron.d/anacron`

From steeldriver  in the comments